# How to use subquery with SQL group by?

Tags: sql

```
select CONCAT(P.ad,'',p.soyad),P.personel_no,
sum(P.maas) as toplammaas,(SELECT P.maas-P.prim FROM personel)
from personel AS P
group by p.personel_no,concat(P.ad,'',p.soyad)
```

I wrote this code but I got an error. Why do I have an error?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? What **IS** the error?

Comment: "SELECT P.maas-P.prim FROM personel" would need to return a single value. You would need to post your error.

Comment: Please provide you sample data and table basic schema to check what it gone wrong. :)

Comment: _subquery returned more than 1 row_?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.  Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would help -- you might be surprised but a non-working query often does not convey much information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need that subquery. You can do simple arithmetic directly in your SELECT clause.

```sql
select CONCAT(P.ad,'',p.soyad),P.personel_no,
       sum(P.maas) as toplammaas,
       sum(P.maas-P.prim) as diff
from personel AS P
group by p.personel_no,concat(P.ad,'',p.soyad)
```

But it's possible I don't understand what you need. You didn't explain in very much detail.